# AppBarLayout / CollapsingToolbarLayout expands indefinitely

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-support-design, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to use the AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout to have a collapsible toolbar with an image that fades away while scrolling up but the toolbar remains.

The problem is when I set both AppBarLayout & CollapsingToolbarLayout `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"`, the toolbar fills the entire screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/be1m6.png

When I set `android:layout_height = "200dp"`, the height is fixed, but it doesn't work with the NestedScrollView and resize.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTao2.png

Here's the xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/articleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gmail.senokt16.bosphoruschronicle.ArticleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/articleCollapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/article_app_bar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/articleActivityImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/article_app_bar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                layout="@layout/article_app_bar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleActivityContents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/articleFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hello MrHappy I recommend you take a look to this excelent project on GitHub https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare there is a full example of using android support design library, include the use:
Collapsing Toolbar
FloatingActionButton
View anchoring
NavigationView
Snackbar.
Hope that can help you

Comment: @darkangelo I've made some changes based on the example you gave, and there is some improvement. It's like the second picture but whenever I scroll to either end of the NestedScrollView, the AppBarLayout moves like 10dp. It still doesn't follow the scrolling properly though. I'll make another question since the original issue seems to be somewhat resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.

First, I removed `<include>` and added the toolbar manually.

It still happened, so after some fiddling I found that it happens because my toolbar had a `minimumHeight`, but `layout_height=wrap_content`. I changed it to `layout_height=?attr/actionbarsize`, and it worked. Here is my example. (The FrameLayout has a nestedscrollview like yours inside.)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"
                    />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did some changes on the code and fixed the issue somewhat. Now I have another problem:
[CollapsingToolbarLayout & NestedScrollView don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073980/collapsingtoolbarlayout-nestedscrollview-dont-work-together)